# How do I get access to edit a config file in a WindowsApps Folder?

Tags: windows-10, ark-survival-evolved

I have a Windows 10 machine and a version of Ark I installed from the Windows Store. There is a certain Dino that shall remain nameless that I just don't want in my game anymore but I cannot edit the game.ini file.

I have taken ownership of the folder and its contents, I have explicitly added the local admin to the folder and it's contents and I still cannot edit the file.

I do not have a copy of the default file so I have not tried using a recovery console and powershell to overwrite the file but if someone can tell me where to get the default .ini file then I will certainly give this a shot. I did try making a copy of the file to my documents folder but windows told me that I needed the permission of the user I was already logged in as to copy the file.

I am running 1909 build 18363.657.

Let me know if you can help me out.

Update 20200215:
Attempting to open any ini file with either Notepad or Notepad++ running with elevated privileges results in "You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission."

Comment: are you running notepad with elevated/admin privileges? (Run notepad as admin first, then open the file. Not that you should be having this problem on what should be a normal file)

Comment: Since you're essentially having trouble editing/copying a file, you may have better luck asking about this on https://superuser.com, instead.

Comment: @smock I have tried both notepad and notepad++ as admin.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to edit your local .ini configurations on the Win 10 Microsoft Store version of Ark. You will actually have Ark files in 2 different locations. The first being inside the WindowsApps folder which as far as i can tell is not editable. I have attempted several different ways to edit and add files to these folders unsuccessfully. The second place is under your local user profile, and you can find and change your game.ini and gameusersettings.ini here:

> C:\%LocalAppData%\Local\Packages\StudioWildcard.4558480580BB9_1w2mm55455e38\LocalState\Saved"

You can customize your game by editing the game.ini and gameusersettings.ini files. There are several resources on the web that will help you with this.